# how to use a nested variable in echo command

Tags: batch-file

How can I write to use two nested variables at once, like an array? I am trying to make a number of variables specified by the user (array indexes from `1` up to that number) and their names are also specified by the user (array name), but when I do this nothing is returned. Can anyone help me please?

```
echo how many people?
set /p number=
echo.
echo.
for /l %%a in (1,1,%number%) do (
    echo name of %%a person
    set /p s%%a =
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    if %%a==%number% (
        echo names are
        pause
        for /l %%n in (1,1,%number%) do (
            echo name %%n is %s%%a%
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Besides missing delayed expansion, you must remove the _space_ in front of the `=` sign in `set /p s%%a =` for it not to become part of the variable name...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are trying to do is create a pseudo array as batch files do not have arrays natively.  So you need to use delayed expansion to get your expected output.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo how many people?
set /p number=
echo.
echo.
for /l %%a in (1,1,%number%) do (
    echo name of %%a person
    set /p s%%a=
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    if %%a==%number% (
        echo names are
        for /l %%n in (1,1,%number%) do (
            echo name %%n is !s%%n!
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing DelayedExpansion:

In batch a closed block of parentheseis gets calculated at once, so variable values changed within it will not be displayed using the normal `%myVar%` when accessed within it.

To do so however add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at the top of your script and change `%myVar%` to `!myVar!`.

Btw with the command `@echo off` you can suppress a lot of unneccessary command-line output :)

Comment: thanks for the help but can you please explain %myVar% !myVar! i didn't understand what should i replace

Comment: If you have for example `%number%` change it to `!number!` so change `%` to `!`.

Comment: i did nothing happend